# A condition which implies conditionally independent

Tags: probability-theory, independence

This is exercise 1.17 from Le Gall's book, Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus.

Suppose $H$ is a centered Gaussian space and let $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ be linear subspaces of $H$. Let $K$ be a closed linear subspace of $H$. We write $p_{K}$ for the orthogonal projection onto $K$. Show that the condition
$$\forall X_{1} \in H_{1},\forall X_{2} \in H_{2},E[X_{1}X_{2}]=E[p_{K}(X_{1})p_{K}(X_{2})]$$

implies that the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(H_{1})$ and $\sigma(H_{2})$ are conditionally independent given $\sigma(K)$.

Here the conditionally independence means that, for every $\sigma(H_{1})$ -measurable random variable $Y_{1}$, and for every $\sigma(H_{2})$ -measurable random variable $Y_{2}$, on has
$$E[Y_{1}Y_{2}\mid \sigma(K)]=E[Y_{1}\mid \sigma(K)]E[Y_{2}\mid \sigma(K)].$$

How to solve this exercise?

Comment: In your definition, what is the difference between $p_K(X_1)$ and $\mathbb E[X_1|\sigma(K)]$ ?

Comment: @P.Quinton Actually they equal to each other by a theorem before this exercise in this book.

Comment: According to the hint of this exercise, it is enough to consider the case where $Y_1$, resp. $Y_2$,is the indicator function of an event depending only on finitely many variables in $H_1$, resp.in $H_2$. Have you tried that ?